# Android getSerializableExtra returns null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a code which is working normally but sometimes (not always, by **Crashlytics**) I'm getting `NullPointerException` when program is executing `getSerializableExtra(START_DATE)`. I'm always putting there `long` value so it cannot be null. Is it possible to lost extra data?

Starting intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UsersAroundEventOrHotelActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UsersAroundEventOrHotelActivity.PLACE_ID, placeId);
                intent.putExtra(UsersAroundEventOrHotelActivity.PLACE_TYPE, placeType);
                intent.putExtra(UsersAroundEventOrHotelActivity.START_DATE, startDate.getTime());
                intent.putExtra(UsersAroundEventOrHotelActivity.END_DATE, endDate.getTime());
```

Getting data in `onCreate` method:

```
Long placeId = (Long) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PLACE_ID);
        PlaceType placeType = (PlaceType) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PLACE_TYPE);
        Date startDate = new Date((Long) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(START_DATE));
        Date endDate = new Date((Long) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(END_DATE));
```

When I try it with debugger it works like a charm, but some user is getting `NullPointerException` in line `.getSerializableExtra(START_DATE)` Any ideas?

Comment: `Date.getTime()` returns long... why are you trying to get it using `getSerializableExtra` ? why not `getLongExtra` ? **edit:** @TheTanic  true, fixed :)

Comment: Ok i can use this method, but the problem is that using getSerializedExtra is also working, but in some rare situations it is crashing, and I don't know why